# How to prove this trigonometric inequality?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

I am trying to prove the inequality
$$
\begin{aligned}
\cos((b - a) t) - \cos((b + a) t) + 
 t \sqrt{n (n - 1)} (a - b)\sin((a + b) t)\\ - 
 t \sqrt{n (n - 1)} (a + b) \sin((b - a) t)\le0
\end{aligned}
$$
where $a=\sqrt{k/n}$ and $b=\sqrt{k/(n-1)}$ for $t\in[0,1]$, $k>0$ and $n\ge2$.

After plotting this function, I am convinced that the inequality holds. I tried to prove it using derivative with respect to $t$, but ended up with sines and cosines with coefficients getting more and more complicated. Is there a way to prove this?

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos\left((b-a)t\right)=\cos(bt-at)=\cos(bt)\cos(at)+\sin(bt)\sin(at)$$
$$\cos((b+a)t)=\cos(bt)\cos(at)-\sin(bt)\sin(at)$$
$$\cos\left((b-a)t\right)-\cos((b+a)t)=2\sin(bt)\sin(at)$$
try from here

Comment: This is what I use to get the inequality.....

Comment: Then what is your question?

Comment: Well...I mean I reduce another inequality (which I was trying to prove) to the one presented in the problem using this formula you give.

Comment: can you just tell actual question?